# HTTP endpoint that causes string to write to a file

Tags: python, api, flask, postman

the api should include one function called "write text to file" and inputs a string parameter

as for the function to write to the disk I have no problem and I implemented the code my problem is how to set the rest API using python.

EDIT:
this is my code:

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template
)

import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import re

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Welcome'


@app.route('/write_text_to_file', methods=['POST'])
def write_text_to_file():
    f = open("str.txt", "w+")
    f.write("hello world")
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

anyhow when I try to test my rest api:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/write_text_to_file

I am getting the following error:
[image]

Now I'm trying to test my rest-api , however how can I make my code to start the server and to the test the post request api, this is my test_class:

```
import requests
import unittest

API_ENDPOINT="http://127.0.0.1:5000/write_text_to_file"


class test_my_rest_api(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_post_request(self):
        """start the server"""
        r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT)
        res = r.text
        print(res)
```

also when runnning my request using postman I am getting internal_server_error:
[image]

Comment: Python has a built in HTTPServer that you can take a look into.

Comment: Also, for a simple framework, you can try flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: @Gautam - it's compatible with python 2.7?

Comment: @tupacshakur , Yes it is.

Comment: Note: A RESTful webservice is a broad term, and really all youre exposing is a HTTP path as an API. The design of what you have is not exactly "REST"

Comment: Please limit your questions to single question!

Comment: @plaes - no problem sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a `GET` request for this url, but you've specified that this endpoint can only accept `POST`:

`@app.route('/write_text_to_file', methods=['POST'])`

Also, the `SocketServer` and `SimpleHTTPServer` imports are not needed with Flask.

Comment: How do I add the ability to my api post to add parameters ?

Comment: @tupacshakur Please do the Flask tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The method is not allowed because Chrome (or any browser) makes GET requests.

Whereas, you defined it as POST

```
@app.route('/write_text_to_file', methods=['POST'])
```

Either change it to a GET method, or use a tool such as POSTMan to perform other HTTP call types